# How to add images where each represents a different color channel?

Tags: image

So I have three matrices that represent say the R, G, and B channels of an image:

```
mR = RandomInteger[{0, 255}, {2, 2}];
mG = RandomInteger[{0, 255}, {2, 2}];
mB = RandomInteger[{0, 255}, {2, 2}];
```

I would like to add these to get an overall image made of these three channels, but I can't seem to be able to do that. Trying to understand the documentation under "Image", I tried

```
Image[{mR, mG, mB}, "Byte"]
```

but this gives me an image that's 3x2:

[image: RGB]

Also when I try

```
Image[{mR, ConstantArray[0, {2, 2}], ConstantArray[0, {2, 2}]}, "Byte"]
```

I don't get the red channel. I just get the first row of the image above with zeros everywhere else:

[image: R]

I can't understand the documentation here, and any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: @cartonn Should you want to, you could do it in one go with `Image[RandomInteger[{0, 255}, {2, 2, 3}], "Byte"]`...

Comment: @cormullion I assumed the `RandomInteger` part was just to generate a MWE, and in reality the `mR`, `mG`, and `mB` are more complicated.

Comment: @EliLansey yes, I thought that was probably true. Still, good practice for my fingers ... :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the `Interleaving` option for `Image` to specify the colors are not interleaved.

```
Image[{mR, mG, mB}, "Byte", Interleaving -> False]
```

**Update:**

Normally image data is in the form

```
imdata={
 {{r11,g11,b11}, ..., {r1m,g1m,b1m}}, (* First row of pixels *)
 {{r21,g21,b21}, ..., {r2m,g2m,b2m}}, (* Second row of pixels *)
 ...
 {{rn1,gn1,bn1}, ..., {rnm,gnm,bnm}}  (* Last row of pixels *)
}
```

where each `{rij,gij,bij}` represents Red/Blue/Green value for pixel `[[i,j]]` and you can just use `Image[imdata]`

But if you have your image data like:

```
red = { {r11,r12, ..., r1m}, (* Amount of red for each pixel in first row *)
        {r21,r22, ..., r2m}, (*  ... in second row *)
        ...
        {rn1,rn2, ..., rnm}  (*  ... last row *)
      }
green = (* Similarly *)
blue = (*  *)
```

And you want to make an `Image` out of this you let Mathematica know you have it in this form by the `Image[{red,green,blue},Interleaving->False]` option.

You can run the command `ImageData[img,Interleaving->#]&/@{True,False}` on an image to see the difference for a particular image, I recommend a small one.

For 3 pixel wide, 2 pixel high image looking like:

[image: Test image]

```
imdat={
     {{1.,1.,0.},{1.,0.,0.},{0.,0.,1.}},
     {{1.,1.,1.},{0.,1.,0.},{0.,0.,1.}}
     };
{red, green, blue} = ImageData[Image[imdat], Interleaving -> False];
(* You'll now have:
  red   == {{1.,1.,0.},
            {1.,0.,0.}}
  green == {{1.,0.,0.},
            {1.,1.,0.}}
  blue  == {{0.,0.,1.},
            {1.,0.,1.}}
 *)
```

Comment: +1 Much better than my answer. I'd consider this the "right" way.

Comment: This works, but could you explain "interleaving" a bit more? What does it mean to have colors interleaved? The documentation is again superficial, as far as I can tell.

Comment: @cartonn I updated the question with an explanation of the difference

Answer (score 3):

First make each one of them an image:

```
images = Image[ #, "Byte"]&/@{mR,mG,mB}
```

[image]

Then use `ColorCombine`:

```
ColorCombine[images, "RGB"]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You could also combine the data yourself before making it into an image.  We want to take the three matrices and list each corresponding component together:

```
MapThread[List, {mR, mG, mB}, 2]
```

This gives a matrix of RGB triplets as required.  You can then throw that at `Image`.